# apostrophe in JSON is causing errors on server

Tags: javascript, json, special-characters, html-encode, stringify

I have a string that I'm doing a JSON.stringify(str) on in Javascript. The string is L'Oreal.

However, as this variable gets passed around before the JSON.stringify happens, its value becomes

L& #39;Oreal(without the space between & and #), and the resulting JSON string that i send to the server is being recognized as potentially dangerous and I get a server side error.

My question is, how do I avoid the apostrophe getting replaced by <&#39>; before the stringify call, or an alternate way to solve this?

EDIT 1:
Here's some code that is causing this, its quite basic -

```
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numrows; rowIndex++)
{
     var cellValues = new Array();
     for (var cellIndex=0; cellIndex < numCols; cellIndex++)
     {
          cellValues[cellIndex] = someInputArray[cellIndex]; //One of the values that gets populated here inlcudes the word L'Oreal
     }
     rowValues[rowIndex] = cellValues; //After this assignment, rowValues[0][3] which was earlier L'Oreal becomes L&#39;Oreal
}

var jsonToSend = JSON.stringify(rowValues);
```

I tried to build a jsFiddle but I do not see this happening there in this very basic example which mimics the # of times the string gets assigned in the actual code.

**EDIT 2: I know why this is happening now. We HTML Encode the data when it comes from the server to avoid XSS injection. While it displays alright, when I convert this data to JSON, it results in ill-formed JSON which the server recognizes as potentially dangerous and throws an exception.**

Server-side code (.Net C#)- WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Data);

Still don't know what a good way to handle this might be.

Comment: Show the code that's causing the character to be replaced by an entity in the first place.

Comment: Need to see some code, please.

Comment: Any reason you're using `new Array()` instead of `[]`?  It has nothing to do with the apostrophe problem, but using `[]` really is the best way to create an array.

Comment: Hi @Derek, no reason really, just didn't know that. Could you explain why?

Comment: There are many sources online that explain this, but here's one:  http://blog.chomperstomp.com/new-array-vs-in-javascript/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "This is a test string with L&#39;Oreal in it.";
var regex = /&#39;/g;
var output = JSON.stringify(str.replace(regex, "'"));
$('#test').html(output);
```

You can use a regular expression to sniff out the special character code and replace it back before stringifying it. NOTE: the "g" in the regex above makes the search global so it will replace any instance of "'". The above code should work. Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating. http://jsfiddle.net/pJD9X/1/

EDIT: Alternate whitelist approach. You could possibly create a whitelist of special characters and take an approach that is similar to how underscor.js actually encodes stuff. Only instead of encoding you will be decoding. NOTE: this is possibly a dangerous solution because it allows your code to decode special characters

```
var str = "This is a test string with L&#39;Oreal in it and an ampersand &#38; in it";
var whiteList = {
    "&#39;":"'",
    "&#38;":"&"
};
var specialCharDecoder = /&#39;|&#38;/g;
function htmlDecode (string) {
    return ('' + string).replace(specialCharDecoder, function (match) {
       return whiteList[match]; 
    });
}
var output = htmlDecode(str);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid the replacement in the first place?  Otherwise, yes, this is a valid option.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid this if possible

Comment: @neuDev33 would you like to avoid this because of performance concerns? Only asking to see if there is another solution we can come up with based on your concern.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I'd like to avoid this because my input data can contain a lot of different special chars besides the apostrophe. So my solution would have to be generic. I'm updating the question with additional data i came across today.

Comment: Hi @neuDev33 I've updated my answer above with a possible solution. I'm not aware of a good generic way to handle this, but perhaps a whiltelist approach would suffice. Just be care full when decoding special chars as it could be dangerous in certain instances.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for the options. I cannot whitelist the special characters because theres no way i can predict which ones will be used. I found an alternate approach to do this, documented below.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution that Mike gave will work fine for isolated cases, in my situation the user could enter information with any special characters and there's no way to predict a set of special characters that will be used.

In order to over come this, I'm manually decoding each value before JSONifying it -

```
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numrows; rowIndex++)
{
    var cellValues = new Array();
    for (var cellIndex=0; cellIndex < numCols; cellIndex++)
    {//FIX BELOW
        cellValues[cellIndex] = $('<div />').html(someInputArray[cellIndex]).text(); //manually decode
    }
    rowValues[rowIndex] = cellValues; 
}

var jsonToSend = JSON.stringify(rowValues);
```

Comment: I just realised that this is not a good solution. This willl eave your app exposed to XSS injection. Here's more information - http://benv.ca/2012/10/4/you-are-probably-misusing-DOM-text-methods/